# How to adjust the passport size picture on the top left of CV?

Tags: cv

```
I want to adjust the passport size picture on the top left of CV.

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,multicol}
%\usepackage{doublespace}
%\setstretch{1.2}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CV}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,urlcolor=blue}

\setlength{\textwidth}{5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{660pt}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{42pt} 
\setlength{\topmargin}{-20pt}

\newcommand{\ingreen}[1]{{\color{blue}#1}}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
%\huge{\textsc{Curriculum Vitae}}
%\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
\huge{\textsc{Name}}
\end{center}
%\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Contact Information}
\begin{flushleft}

Email: \ingreen{abc@gmail.com} \\
Skype: abc\\
Mobile: +00-000-1234567 \\
Phone: +00-00-1234567
\end{flushleft}

\section{Objective}
\begin{flushleft}
 To become a good researcher in my field.
\end{flushleft}

\section{Education}

\begin{CV}
\item[\ingreen{August 2007--August 2009}]
\item[Master(Biochemistry)]
\item[University Name]
\item[City, Country]
\item[Area: Biochemistry]
\item[\ingreen{August 2002--September 2006}]
\item[BS(Hons)]
\item[University Name]
\item[City, Country]
\item[Area: Biology]
\end{CV}
\section{Research Work}
\begin{flushleft} My Master degree thesis is on \emph{Research}.
\end{flushleft}

\section{Technical Expertise}
\noindent
\begin{itemize}
\item  MATLAB, Mathematica, C/C++, \LaTeX, \LaTeX Draw, Mayura Draw, MS   Office
\end{itemize}

\section{Area of Interest}
\noindent
\vfill
\columnbreak
\section{Hobbies $\&$ Sports}
\noindent
\begin{itemize}
\item Studying Books, Cricket, Watching Sports Channels
\item Music, Movies, Photography
\end{itemize}


\section{References}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \usepackage{graphicx}
      \usepackage{tikz}
      \usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

       \begin{document}

       \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
       \node[anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt] at (current page text area.north east) 
       {\includegraphics[height=4cm]{rick.jpg}};  
       \end{tikzpicture}

Comment: There is no picture that could be adjusted. I vote to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with the `includegraphics` command from the `graphicx` package ?
You can specify the size of the picture.
For example :

`\includegraphics[width=3cm]{../img/photo}`